# C++ expression must have class type with class template

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to an Array class with a template and I have a problem.

List.h:

```
template<class T>
class Array
{
private:
    T** List;
    int Capacity; 
    int Size; 
public:
    Array(); 
    ~Array();
    Array(int capacity);
    Array(const Array<T>& otherArray); 
    int GetSize();
    int GetCapacity();
};
```

And the List.cpp file looks like

```
#include "List.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

template<class T>
Array<T>::Array()
{
    printf("Default constructor called!\n");
    Capacity = 0;
    Size = 0;
}

template<class T>
Array<T>::~Array()
{
    delete List;
    Capacity = 0;
    Size = 0;
}

template<class T>
int Array<T>::GetCapacity()
{
    return Capacity;
}
```

And the main :

```
int main()
{
    Array<char> A(); //Calling the default constructor
    std::cout << A.GetCapacity();
}
```

I am calling the default constructor but I don't get anything in the console. I think that I did something wrong with the constructor call or with the constructor declaration.

Comment: `Array<char>A();` declares a function called `A` that returns a `Array<char>`

Comment: You don't get output in console because your program never ran. You got a compilation error.

Comment: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sMffq2

Comment: @chris it runs without the last ```cout```

Comment: @idclev463035818 then how am I supposed to call the default constructor?

Comment: get rid of the brackets: `Array<char> A;` also AAA helps here: `auto A = Array<char>;`

Comment: @ValentinGrigorean, My unstated point is that Clang can give a perfectly comprehensible warning here. If a compiler error is giving you trouble on one compiler, try another.

Comment: @ValentinGrigorean Because without last `cout` you never use `A`. And the syntax that uses default constructor would be (simply) `Array<char> A;` or (with uniform initialization) `Array<char> A {};` or (slightly longer) `Array<char> A = Array<char>();`

Comment: @idclev463035818 I am getting unresolved external for ```Array<char> A``` and type name is not allowed for ```auto A = Array<char>```

Comment: thats a problem then that is no present in the code you posted. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: did you maybe put the definitions for the template in a source file?

Comment: @idclev463035818 I've updated the post

Comment: Yes, you put your template definitions in a source file. Delete `List.cpp` put all the code in `List.h`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Thank you! The problem was because of the template definitions being in a different file